# Mysql sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, query, select, subquery

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN 
(
(SELECT courses  FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) OR 
(SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT courses FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) AND meta_key ='post_id' )
) 
AND 
ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_locations_courses WHERE location_id = 1120)
```

I am having the problem with above query while i am using `IN` with sub queries gave me the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row` why it happens when i am using `IN` clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        (SELECT courses  FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) 
        OR 
        (SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT courses FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) AND meta_key ='post_id' )
```

This is a condition, but you need `n` values.

This should work:

```
(
    ID IN 
        (
            (SELECT courses  FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) 
        )
    OR
    ID IN 
        (
            (SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  post_id IN 
                (SELECT courses FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) AND meta_key ='post_id' )
        )
)
```

Also take care about subqueries with MySQL. In your case a sub- subquery.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356784/mysql-dependent-sub-query-with-not-in-in-the-where-clause-is-very-slow

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN 
(
   (SELECT courses  FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) OR 
   (SELECT  meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE  post_id IN (SELECT courses FROM wp_category WHERE CatID =401) AND meta_key ='post_id' )
) 
AND 
ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_locations_courses WHERE location_id = 1120);
```

Re-write those nasty subqueries to simply check for existence on the resultant join partitions:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM
       (
            SELECT courses, cat_ID FROM wp_category
                UNION  -- union for OR
            SELECT meta_value AS "courses", cat_ID 
                FROM wp_postmeta, wp_category 
                WHERE post_id=courses AND meta_key ='post_id' 
       ) A, wp_locations_courses -- join for AND
          WHERE 
             ( wp_posts.ID, 1120 ) IN ( post_id, location_id ) AND  -- resultant join #1
             ( wp_posts.ID, 401 ) IN ( courses, cat_ID )  -- resultant join #2
    );
```

This makes it worthwhile to index and partition the three reference tables accordingly, particularly if there are many potential different cat_IDs with many records on each.